# Copy contents of System.Data. DataTable To List<T> with Automapper C#

Tags: c#, datatable, automapper, data-conversion

I have looked but I have not found the answer to my question.
I'm trying to use Automapper to get the contents from a DataTable to a List in C#.

I have already mapped the structure:

```
List<T> ReadData<T>(DataTable dt)
{
     return Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<T>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
} 


ListOfData = ReadData<DataModel>(DataTableOfData);
```

My DataTableOfData has a count of 80.
My ListOfData also gets a count of 80 at runtime.
Each element, however, remains at a 01-01-0001 00:00:00 / null value, where as the same element in de DataTableOfData has information in it.
So My automapper is failing somewhere. However, I can not figure it out.

I thought about using a for each to assign each element but I can not figure it out;

```
ListOfData = ReadData<DataModel>(DataTableOfData).ForEach(e => e.startdate etc
```

But I am stuck at how to go on about this.
Theres 3 values in total per DataModel (and like I said the datatable contains 80 models of that type).
A startdate, an enddate and a subject. First two are DateTime, last one is a string value.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I made a mistake in the mapping process in that my Model and my List fieldnames where not the same so the mapping process failed.